# InitCap equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I want to know what is the equivalent for 'InitCap' in Oracle to SQL Server without creating an additional function like 'dbo.initcap()'. Can anyone help me how to get this without using a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to update data as upper case first letter with t-sql command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688182/how-to-update-data-as-upper-case-first-letter-with-t-sql-command)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try it with something like

```
concat(ucase(substr(yourstring, 1,1)), substr(yourstring, 2))
```

Comment: The above code capitalizes only the first character of the string. Oracle's InitCap capitalizes the first letter of **EACH** word.

Comment: concat(upper(substring ('yourstring', 1,1)), lower(substring('yourstring', 2,len('yourstring'))))