# Making first letter of every word upper case with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a text which looks something like this `VENDOR CORPORATION (GA/ATL)`. I want to make it look like `Vendor Corporation (GA/ATL)`.

So, I want to make only the first letter of every word upper case except those words which exists between `(` and `)`.

I came across - `UPPER(LEFT(FIELD_NAME,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(FIELD_NAME,2,LEN(FIELD_NAME)))`, but it handles only one word at a time and doesn't have the functionality I want. A function which can do the job is most desired.

Comment: I think you'll need to write a user-defined function for this very specific purpose.

Comment: Which you call from triggers, to make sure stored data always have the correct format.

Comment: This function is called InitCap. You need to adjust a solution like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11688803/21336 handle parens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [function](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/initcap.aspx) like this:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @Index          INT
DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(255)

SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
SET @Index = 1

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
    SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                    END

    IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
    BEGIN
        IF  @PrevChar != '(' AND @PrevChar != '/'
            SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
        IF  @PrevChar = '(' 
            SET @OutputString = LEFT(@OutputString, LEN(@OutputString) - LEN(SUBSTRING(@OutputString, CHARINDEX('(',@OutputString), CHARINDEX(')',@OutputString)))) +  UPPER(SUBSTRING(@OutputString, CHARINDEX('(',@OutputString), CHARINDEX(')',@OutputString)))
    END

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN @OutputString

END
```

**USAGE**

```
SELECT [dbo].[InitCap]('VENDOR CORPORATION (GA/ATL)')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Vendor Corporation (GA/ATL)
```

Comment: needs more work to handle `except those words which exists between ( and )`

Comment: just a heads up.. i had to edit my answer after i realized words after `(` and `)` were not being handled correctly.  your function will also turn `'VENDOR CORPORATION (GA/ATL) duhh duhh'` into `'Vendor Corporation (GA/ATL) DUHH DUHH'` not sure if that's an issue

Comment: @JamieD77 Its not an issue as my strings doesn't have any text after `)` but smart observation!

Answer (score 2):

Using the Jeff Moden splitter (which can be found here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) this can be accomplished. You then need to use a cross tab, also known as a conditional aggregate to put the piece back together. You could also do this with a PIVOT but I find the cross tab less obtuse for syntax and it has been proven to be slightly faster performance wise. This is also using the InitCap function found here. [How to update data as upper case first letter with t-sql command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688182/how-to-update-data-as-upper-case-first-letter-with-t-sql-command/11688803#11688803)

```
declare @Value varchar(100) = 'VENDOR CORPORATION (GA/ATL)';

with sortedValues as
(
    select Case when left(s.Item, 1) = '(' then s.Item else dbo.InitCap(s.Item) end as CorrectedVal
        , s.ItemNumber
    from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@Value, ' ') s
)

select MAX(case when ItemNumber = 1 then CorrectedVal end) + ' '
     + MAX(case when ItemNumber = 2 then CorrectedVal end) + ' '
     + MAX(case when ItemNumber = 3 then CorrectedVal end)
from sortedValues
```

If you don't know ahead of time how many "words" you will have you can adjust this crosstab to a dynamic version. You can read more about the dynamic crosstab here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

--EDIT--

Thanks to JamieD77 for a suggestion using STUFF. I particularly like this option because I have another version of InitCap that uses a tally table instead of the version referenced here which uses a while loop. Using STUFF facilitates turning this whole thing into an inline table valued function so it will be super fast. If anybody wants to see the InitCap without looping let me know and I will be happy to post it.

Here is the query using the suggested STUFF methodology.

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT   ' ' + s.CorrectedVal
    FROM sortedValues s
    ORDER BY s.ItemNumber
    FOR
    XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')
```

Comment: @JamieD77 I like the STUFF option quite a bit. I have another InitCap function that I use which doesn't use looping, it is tally table based so using STUFF like this will keep everything without any loops at all. I will update my answer with that.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the above answers.  If you want to just ignore what is between `(` and `)` you can use this slightly modified version of the [**InitCap**](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/initcap.aspx) function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap] (
     @InputString VARCHAR(4000)
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS 
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @Index INT
        DECLARE @Char CHAR(1)
        DECLARE @PrevChar CHAR(1) = ' '
        DECLARE @OutputString VARCHAR(255)
        SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
        SET @Index = 1
        WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString) 
            BEGIN
                SET @Char = SUBSTRING(@InputString,@Index,1)
                IF @Char = '(' 
                    BEGIN
                        WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
                            AND @Char NOT IN (')') 
                            BEGIN 
                                SET @Index = @Index + 1
                                SET @PrevChar = @Char
                                SET @Char = SUBSTRING(@InputString,@Index,1)
                                SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString,@Index,1,@Char)
                            END
                    END              
                IF @PrevChar IN (' ',';',':','!','?',',','.','_','-','/','&','''') 
                    BEGIN
                        IF @PrevChar != ''''
                            OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S' 
                            SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString,@Index,1,UPPER(@Char))
                    END
                SET @Index = @Index + 1
                SET @PrevChar = @Char
            END
        RETURN @OutputString
    END
GO
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
SELECT  [dbo].[InitCap](n)
FROM    ( VALUES ( 'VENDOR CORPORATION (GA/ATL)'), 
                 ( 'VENDOR CORPORATION (ga/atl)'), 
                 ( 'VENDOR CORPORATION (Ga/Atl)') ) t (n)

output
--------
Vendor Corporation (GA/ATL)
Vendor Corporation (ga/atl)
Vendor Corporation (Ga/Atl)
```

if you always want to CAPS everything inside `(` and `)` simply use `SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString,@Index,1,UPPER(@Char))` in both places

Comment: You made it look really simple. Great answer.