# SQL upper case function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with an SQL task (Microsoft SQL Server 2008).

This is the task: Show name and surname of clients in a way that first letters of name and surname are upper case (for example Michael Jackson).
I don't know how to write it in SQL. I know that it would be something like this:

```
select UPPER(name), UPPER(surname) from client ;
```

But it shows *all* the letters in an upper form.

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/initcap.aspx

Comment: Posible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054/whats-the-best-way-to-capitalise-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-s

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288465/t-sql-function-to-convert-a-varchar-in-this-instance-someones-name-from-upp

Comment: The usual approach would be to ensure that names are properly capitalised in the database. You then don't need any `UPPER` function. (I understand this isn't suitable for you, but it may be for someone else asking the same question who finds this one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING` to `UPPER` just the first letter of the first name and surname, then concatenate them to the rest of the first name and surname respectively:

```
select
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(name, 2, LEN(name)),
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(surname, 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(surname, 2, LEN(surname))
from client;
```

While this should address your stated problem, note that it will not properly handle capitalization *within* surnames (e.g. in `'MacDowell'`), which would require additional logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(20) = 'michael';
DECLARE @LastName  NVARCHAR(20) = 'jackson';

SELECT UPPER(LEFT(@FirstName, 1)) + RIGHT(@FirstName, LEN(@FirstName)-1) AS FirstName
      ,UPPER(LEFT(@LastName, 1))  + RIGHT(@LastName, LEN(@LastName)-1) AS LastName
```

Result

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╗
║ FirstName ║ LastName ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╣
║ Michael   ║ Jackson  ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╝
```