# How can I convert the first character of a column to an uppercase for every row?

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (MAX)   NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);
```

Can someone give me some advice on how I could convert the first letter of the column English to upper case in all of the rows?

Comment: You can use `LEFT()`, `UPPER()` and `REPLACE()` functions within an `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-Sql function to convert a varchar - in this instance someone's name - from upper to title case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288465/t-sql-function-to-convert-a-varchar-in-this-instance-someones-name-from-upp)

Comment: Aside from the question you have a very bad key structure here. When you use a guid as your clustered index you will exceed 99.999% index fragmentation with just a few thousand rows. You have to constantly defrag this of your index will be essentially useless if not actually slower than no index at all. There are dozens of articles discussing this, here is one of the best ones. http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/

Comment: @SeanLange, good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way without using `STUFF`, though I like `STUFF` better

```
Update phrase set English = upper(left([English],1)) + right([English], len([English]) - 1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry.  Maybe I was not clear.  I need to update that column so the first character is upper case.

Comment: `Update phrase set English = ....` then use the statement above in either answer @Alan

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(PhraseId INT,English VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'this'),(2,'is'),(3,'easy');

UPDATE @tbl SET English=STUFF(English,1,1,UPPER(LEFT(English,1)));

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Comment: I'm sorry.  Maybe I was not clear.  I need to update that column so the first character is upper case.